# Calculate column wise sum for each row & add new columns for each value in dataframe

Tags: r

I have dataframe as below

```
A     B   C   D
11   11  33  44
11   11  22  33
22   22  33  44
22   33  44  11
```

I have such thousands of rows . 
Dataframe has only these four values 11, 22,33,44.

No NA or blank values

I want to take count for each of these values across every row and add them under new column.

I want output as below -

```
A     B   C   D  11  22  33  44
11   11  33  44   2   0   1   1
11   11  22  33   2   1   1   0
22   22  33  44   0   2   1   1
22   33  44  11   1   1   1   1
```

Currently i am trying 
as

```
count.22 <- sapply(dff,FUN=function(x,dff){sum(dff[,2]==22)},dff)
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
df2 <- cbind(df1,  mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1))))
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2
#   A  B  C  D 11 22 33 44
#1 11 11 33 44  2  0  1  1
#2 11 11 22 33  2  1  1  0
#3 22 22 33 44  0  2  1  1
#4 22 33 44 11  1  1  1  1
```

---

Or we can use `apply` from `base R` to loop over the rows

```
cbind(df1, t( apply(df1, 1, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c(11, 22, 33, 44))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data.frame is `x` you can do it as follows:

```
vals <- c(11,22,33,44)
cbind(x, setNames(lapply(vals, function(v) rowSums(x == v)), vals))
#   A  B  C  D 11 22 33 44
#1 11 11 33 44  2  0  1  1
#2 11 11 22 33  2  1  1  0
#3 22 22 33 44  0  2  1  1
#4 22 33 44 11  1  1  1  1
```

This way you don't loop over the rows but the unique values you want to check.

A similar version with direct assignment would be

```
x[,as.character(vals)] <- lapply(vals, function(v) rowSums(x == v))
```